# Python Random Random

Tags: python, python-2.7

ho i making the random number be below the random number before.

```
 if Airplane==1:
 while icounter<4:
    ifuelliter=random.randrange(1,152621)
    #litter/kilometer
    LpK=152620/13500
    km=LpK*ifuelliter


    ipca=random.randrange(0,50)
    ipcb=random.randrange(0,50)
    ipcc=random.randrange(0,812)


    #3D space distance calculation
    idstance= math.sqrt((icba-ipca)**2 + (icbb-ipcb)**2 + (icbc-ipcc)**2)

    totaldist=km-idstance

    if totaldist>0:
          print "You have enoph fuel to get to New York AirPort"
          print ifuelliter,LpK,km,ipca,ipcb,ipcc,idstance
          icounter=3

    if totaldist<=0:

         print "You dont have enoph fuel to get to New York AirPort please go to the nearest one or you will die"
         print ifuelliter,LpK,km,ipca,ipcb,ipcc,idstance
         icounter=icounter+1
```

whati mean that the "ipca , ipcb , ipcc," i need that they will grow down and not chust a other number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the second parameter of randrange with the previous value:

```
import random
a = random.randrange(0,50)
b = random.randrange(0,a)
while b > a:
    b = random.randrange(0,a)
```

By the way, be careful if your indenting style at the beginning of your code

```
if Airplane == 1:
while ....
```

Should be

```
if Airplane == 1:
    while ....
```